# spacemacs common-lisp inspect value in a new buffer

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

I'm new to lisp and emacs. I setup a common-lisp ide with spacemacs (add common-lisp layer), sbcl and everything works fine.

Only one thing, when I click "Inspect" in right-click menu of a value in slime-repl buffer, the slime-inspect buffer over takes the slime-repl buffer. Then I have to switch back to the slime-buffer manually.

What I want is after clicking inspect, slime-inspect split to the right without taking place any openning buffer.

thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think this question is not really tied to Slime and/or Lisp, I checked the source code and the inspector uses `pop-to-buffer` which in turns relies on `display-buffer`, and there are different ways of configuring emacs to indicate how an existing or new buffer is shown, if the current window is split or not, etc. (as a matter of fact, it does split on my machine but I could not yet understand exactly why). I think you may have more chance asking there: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/display-buffer-alist